# Android shared_prefs values padded with AAAAA

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, hash, sharedpreferences

I have started looked into some Android apps and a mine of information is stored in the shared_prefs file, some of this is in plaintext however some other values are just padded with AAAAA[continues]

For example a game I've looked at, if you collect all the gems on each level you get a crown for that level to say you've 100% this level. Looking at the shared_prefs the field is

```
<string name="levelCrowns">AQHqBwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[continues]</string>
```

However if you play the game and win crowns the AAAA change characters. This leads me to believe that the A's are just padding and a value is written to it when you successfully win a crown.

My question is this some sort of hashing that can be reverse engineered to find what the pattern is, or modified in any way to 'fake' new crowns.

Crowns obtained on level 1 and 3:

```
<string name="levelCrowns">AQHqBwE**A**AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[continues]</string>
```

Crowns obtained on level 1-5:

```
<string name="levelCrowns">AQHqBwE**B**AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[continues]</string>
```

The game is built using Unity3D, in case its an inbuilt Unity hash or something.

Comment: Unless you know how the string was ciphered, you can not decipher it. And it is ciphered exactly to avoid what you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand that, but things like MD5, SHA1, Base64 can be bruteforced and there are websites to reverse these. I'm more curious as to what the AAAA's are, and how they got there, I only really see this technique in games, so leads me to think its a Unity thing.

Comment: In most encryption algorithms padding is added to the the original string so that the size of the (string + padding) can be dividable by the size of the key